# Downgrade gradle version from 7.4 to 7.1.1 in android

Tags: android, gradle

I have created the native android project with Androidx and by default gradle 7.4 installed. But we want to degrade the gradle to 7.1.1 for my project requirement. I have tried to change in the `gradle-wrapper.properties - (distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip)` but getting the below error,

```
Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.4. Current version is 7.1.1.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Change Gradle version in Gradle wrapper to 7.4 and re-import project
Open Gradle wrapper properties
Gradle Settings.
```

I have cleared the cache once but no luck. Can any one suggest the workaround for this issue.

Comment: The error says "Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.4", which seems pretty clear that you won't be able to use 7.1.1.

Comment: @ianhannballake, Actually we have one android library and using v7 Appcomp acttivity. And we are trying to call and its giving error, `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity`

Comment: I don't know what that has to do with your Gradle version - that seems like a completely separate question?